# Display ASP.Net PDF file from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, pdf

I want to get pdf path from sql server database and display it in part of asp.net page .. I tried to put it inside iframe but many browsers force it to download instead of view in it .. I also tried to use pdf.js but can't figure it out how to work correctly .. can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of this are having a problem with? It sounds like you are able to retrieve it from sql and are having a problem displaying it in the browser? It would require some sort of webcontrol that can read the pdf and convert it to html so you can view it on the page. This not typical behavior for a pdf document and you would likely have to create your own control for this sort of thing.

Comment: `"many browsers force it to download instead of view"` - That's a browser setting, you can't change that from the server.  All the server can do is respond to the request with the file contents and headers.  If you've done that, then you're displaying a PDF.  What the browser does with the PDF is the browser's business.

Comment: @SeanLange yeah, the problem in displaying it inside page I didn't deal with webcontrols before

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @David I really don't know what browsers will my customers using it viewing my website

Comment: @karim.fone: That's correct.  Welcome to web development :)  The server responds with the content, from there it's up to the browser.

Comment: The point is that unless you create your own logic for reading these docs it will send the doc the response and it is up to the browser to determine what to do with it.